# asyncio aiohttp - client read of closed file error

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

This is the code:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
session = aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop)
data = {'file': open('test_img.jpg', 'rb')}

async def start():
        async with session.post("http://localhost", data=data) as response:
            text = await response.text()
            print(text)

loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*[start() for i in range(20)]))
```

I get an error:

```
ValueError: read of closed file
```

However if I move the `open()` call to inside the start() function, it works. But I don't want to open the file multiple times.

Comment: Yes, though I'm still wondering why the same code is working with `requests`. using the `files=` argument

Comment: Good question. Does it actually _work_ (correctly), or does it just not raise an exception? Perhaps `requests` reads the file through to the end, but doesn't close it, so all requests other than the first one work with zero-length data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `open(...)` returns a [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), and you're passing the same file object to all `start()` coroutines you are creating at top-level. The coroutine instance that happens to be scheduled first will transfer the file object to `session.post()` as part of the `data` parameter, and `session.post()` will read the file to the end and close the file object. The next `start()` coroutine will try to read from the now-closed object which will raise the exception.

To fix the issue without opening the file multiple times, you need to make sure to actually *read* the data as a bytes object:

```
data = {'file': open('test_img.jpg', 'rb').read()}
```

This will pass the same bytes object to all coroutines, which should work as intended.